# implementing UML diagram to java code (uses both aggregation and polymorphism)

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, uml, aggregation

I'm working on a java exercise that has me a bit confused. How can I use polymorphism while the methods are in an interface? Some help would be appreciated.

Setters and getters can be omitted.

What I have so far:

Interface:

```
interface Interface {
    public void start();
    public void stop();
}
```

First Class:

```
class Class1 implements Interface {

    private String brand;

    @Override
    public void start() { 
    System.out.println("Hello from start"); }

    @Override
    public void stop() { 
    System.out.println("Hello from stop");}
}
```

Class 2:

```
class Class2 implements Interface {

    private String plate;

    @Override
    public void start() { 
   System.out.println("Hello from start");
   }

    @Override
    public void stop() { 
    System.out.println("Hello from stop");}
    }
```

Aggregation Class:

```
class Aggregate {

    private String destination;
    private String starting;

    public void trip(interface : Interface) {
        interface = new Aggregate(Interface);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface in java, is a collection of abstract methods. When a class implements an interface, it inherits the abstract methods of the interface, so that the class can add a body to those methods specifically for itself. In other words, the class can `override` those methods mentioned in the interface. I believe you know that `overriding` and `overloading` are  two types of polymorphism in java. So, in your answer above, you have indeed used polymorphism correctly. Just, add a simple method body relevant to the class, like printing something to the screen (as mentioned in the assignment), in order to add more meaning.

Comment: I think I understand what you were saying about the collection of abstract methods. I just made some edits to add basic systemouts. Would you say that the code I have above is complete?

Comment: i think you should add private fields for Bike and Bus in the Travel class too, in order to represent the aggregation relationships. No need of getters and setters, because the assignment says they can be omitted. yes i think, then the code is complete.